# File uploads - Inherit Permissions - VSFTPD & Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

When uploading files via FTP, they are inheriting the appropriate owner and group, but the permissions are incorrect.

My group is webdev, the user I'm using is ryan, and he is part of the webdev group as displayed by the output of the following:

```
ryan@INTRANET01:/var/www/vision$ getent group webdev
webdev:x:1001:www-data,ryan,admin*
```

When I upload a new file, it looks like this:

```
--w--wx--T  1 ryan webdev     0 Mar 12 09:10 zx.php*
```

The Umask set in vsftpd.conf is 002, which if I'm correct, should equate to rwxrwxr-x.

Permissions on the directory I'm uploading to are 2775.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my file_open_mode setting in vsftpd.conf. It was set to **664** instead of **0666**.

Comment: Looks like you might have lost your user cookie. Registering will prevent such problems in future and you can edit your own posts and accept answers.